How can I render to a specific display with the lowest possible latency using DirectX 12 and Windows 11?
I'm interested in doing some ultra-low-latency rendering for a custom XR device in Windows 11 with DirectX 12.
The device's display appears to Windows as an ordinary monitor, so the standard, naïve approach would be to treat the display as desktop-extended, and render to a fullscreen borderless window on that screen. However, I'm well aware that Windows 11's Desktop Window Manager (DWM) adds significant latency to any window by buffering window frame contents in order to composite them before presenting to the display.
I'm aware that it's possible to disable the DWM, but in Windows 11 this introduces usability issues, and I'm not sure if it's equivalent to the most optimal approach.
(See https://github.com/Dayset/DWM-Killer)
I believe it should also be possible to render to the display in Fullscreen Exclusive mode, but I understand that has limited benefits in Windows 11, and sometimes the OS can override the mode in order to render content that it deems more important on top.
(See https://forums.blurbusters.com/viewtopic.php?t=13940#:~:text=FSE%20still%20exists%20in%20windows,properties%20of%20the%20game's%20executable.)
In an ideal world, the display would be connected but not desktop-extended, and I would be able to use DX12, perhaps combined with a lower level API, to render directly to the display without creating a Window, circumventing Windows and the DWM entirely. If Meta and SteamVR can do it, I feel it must be possible... but how?
As an aside, I've heard that some latency can be gained by using 'Independent Flip' or 'Waitable Flip' models, but can anyone attempt to explain how these work and why they're beneficial?
EDIT: The following post goes some way towards answering my question. I guess rather than exposing some secret low-level API to render directly to a non-desktop display, the VR runtime simply hides the display from the list of displays for desktop extension, but then creates a fairly conventional fullscreen window on that hidden display. I'd still be curious to know more about the latter part of the process though, because again, it implies bypassing the DWM.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314747/windows-how-to-render-to-video-scan-out-memory-directly
